# SQL query error for datetime object

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute this query into my sql database

```
'INSERT INTO ba_shop_opening (day, from, to) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["mon", "1970-01-01 00:00:00", "1970-01-01 00:00:00"]:
```

and I am getting the following error

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to) VALUES ('mon', '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '1970-01-01 00:00:00')' at line 1
```

Here is the DDL of the table I am working with

```
CREATE TABLE `ba_shop_opening` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` datetime NOT NULL,
  `to` datetime NOT NULL,
  'day' VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I don't understand what the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use backticks: (\`day\`, \`from\`, \`to\`)

Comment: And backticks or not, don't use reserved words as table/column names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`from` is a reserved word. I'd recommend you rename the column in the table.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: ahahah, also TO and DAY are reserved kekwords. I just updated the name of the columns and it worked. By the way, the error messages in MySQL sucks! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @krvajal: yes, `DAY` is a keyword in MySQL, but it's not reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

`from` and `to` are *both* [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

In addition, although `date` is not reserved, it is both a function and a data type.

Also, when declaring columns in a table, you should not use single quotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants -- to avoid unexpected errors.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `ba_shop_opening` (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  from_dt datetime NOT NULL,
  to_dt datetime NOT NULL,
  day_of_week VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;

INSERT INTO ba_shop_opening (day_of_week, from_dt, to_dt)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

The column names are cleaner and you don't need to escape any names.

I might suggest that the `datetime` columns are really `time`s, but you don't fully explain the data structure.